# bash: environmental variables within .bashrc

Tags: bash, variables

The following bash function defines two enviromental variable that are going to be used with the script test.sh located on the external usb.

```
quick_function(){

export curent_dir=$(pwd)
export ref_folder="${home}"

local quick_path=$(find /media/$USER -type f -name test.sh)

# run script located on the usb stick from the current directory
chmod +x "$quick_path"
"$quick_path"

}
```

with the aim to produce some test_dir within the current dir (and not on the usb stick, where the script.sh is located). This is test.sh

```
# the both input paths are commented since they have been already provided in the function defined in .bashrc
#curent_dir=$(pwd)
#ref_folder="${home}"
mkdir "$ref_folder"/test_dir
```

For the test purposes I uncomment the $curent_dir and $ref_folder defined in the test.st and (amazingly) found that the script called from the  quick_function () still produces the test_dir in any place from which i opened the terminal (and never on the usb stick ... )

Does it means that for this example I do not need the both enviromental variables exported in the function, or alternatively these variables always overright the variables (with the same names) defined in the subsequently executed script from the same function ?

Comment: Note that it's considered bad form to set environment variables in `.bashrc` -- traditionally, they belong in `.bash_profile` instead, whereas `.bashrc` should be used for things that need to be reestablished for every new interactive shell that's started.

Comment: right, thank you !

Comment: BTW, what's the point of `export curent_dir` at all? The `quick_path` script runs with the same `$PWD` your current shell has (and _do_ prefer `$PWD`, not `$(pwd)` -- much faster to run) so it can check the working directory itself vs needing to inherit it.

Comment: The goal is to create any output filles in any current dir from which I open temrinal but not on the usb stick where the script is located. Initially I thought that it will do everything still on the usb stick where the script located

Comment: Your current directory isn't changed by running an executable located somewhere else; if you're in `~` and you run `/bin/ls`, it lists files in `~`, not files in `/bin`. The same is true for executables (like your script) you create yourself.

Comment: okay thank you. so literally all operations will be performed within the dir from which the current terminal window is opened (not on the usb stick where the test.sh is located), right ?

Comment: If you run `cd /somewhere/else`, _that_ will change the current working directory for things you run after it. If you don't perform a `chdir()` -- as `cd` does -- then your home directory will remain the default working directory relative to which everything else happens.

Comment: If people want to _change that_ and make a script operate relative to its own location, they need to do extra work like what's described at [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The export seem ok. I assume, the problem is with (`export`)`home=$(pwd)`. This looks as if you assumed the variable `home` would contain the path to your home directory (e.g. `/home/yourusername/`). However, `pwd` prints the path to the current directory, so the location of the new directory will always be in your working directory.

Either way, you don't need the environment variables.

- To create the new directory inside your working directory, use `mkdir test_dir`
- To create the new directory inside your home directory, use `mkdir ~/test_dir` or `mkdir "$HOME/test_dir"`.

> produces the test_dir in any place from which i opened the terminal (and never on the usb stick ... )

Sounds like you want to create the new directory on the USB stick, right next to `test.sh`. In that case ...

- you *could* `export ref_folder="$(dirname "$quick_path")"` inside your `quick_function()` *after* `quick_path` was defined and *before* `test.sh` was called
- but it would be way easier to use `dirname` on `$0` or `$BASH_SOURCE` inside `test.sh` instead of manually handling that `ref_folder` variable.

> For the test purposes I uncomment the $home and $ref_folder defined in the test.st and found that the script called from the quick_function() still produces the test_dir in any place from which I opened the terminal

Because the definitions of these variables are the same.

> Does it means [...] [exported] variables always overright the variables (with the same names) defined in the subsequently executed script from the same function ?

Its the other way around! The variables in the inner-most scope (test.sh) shadow the exported variables from the outer scopes (quick_function()).

Comment: Thank you! actually the question was do I need in principle export var that have been already defined within the sh script called from the same function ? I've just tested it on my mac and noticed that the enviromental variables indeed are not required and the test_dir will be always created in the place where I run the function  ..

Comment: @JamesStarlight Whether something is required or not can only be answered if we know your goal. From your question, I can only guess what that goal is. If you need more answers, define your goals inside your question (use the edit button).

Comment: The goal is to create any output filles in any current dir from which I open temrinal but not on the usb stick where the script is located

Comment: @JamesStarlight, if you want to record those values _when you open your terminal_, then you want to record them outside the scope of the function (which runs _later_, when it's called, _not_ when you first opened the terminal).

Comment: @JamesStarlight, ...that said, your home directory -- which will be the current working directory when you start a new terminal in conventional environments -- is just `$HOME`; why store something else with another copy of it?

Comment: okay I understand :-)